Unsure about Khoshnevisan's proof about strong law of large numbers
I'm reading Khoshnevisan's Graduate Probability and I'm not sure about something he says in his proof of the strong law of large numbers. For IID $\{X_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, but maybe not in $\mathcal{L}^2$, and with $E[X_1] = 0$, he defines
$$X'_i = X_i\mathbb{1}_{|X_i|<i}$$
and
$$S'_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X'_i.$$
What he does first is try to prove that $E[S'_n] = o(n)$. But I'm not clear on this proof. First, he shows that
$$|E[S'_n]| \leq E\{|X_1| min(|X_1|, n)\}$$
which I get. But then, he says "[b]y the dominated Convergence theorem, $E[S'_n] = o(n)$ as asserted." But, I'm not seeing that. As $n \to \infty$, this goes to $E\left[|X_1|^2\right]$ which could be infinite.
Am I missing something?

For the second point you missed that it is assumed that $E[X_1]=0$, which you did not write.
For the first point, the random variable $\frac 1n\vert X_1\vert\min(\vert X_1\vert,n)=\vert X_1\vert\min(\frac{\vert X_1\vert}{n},1)$ is obviously dominated by $\vert X_1\vert$ which is by definition integrable, and is smaller than $\frac{\vert X_1\vert^2}{n}$ which vanished as $n$ goes to $+\infty$. So by the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\frac 1n\vert E[S'_n]\vert\le E[\frac 1n\vert X_1\vert\min(\vert X_1\vert,n)]\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$
You wrote

For the second point, I just realized that as and edited the post as you were answering. Sorry about that.

For the first point, I'm still unclear. When we are talking about the DCT here, what I assume they are doing as looking at is $\int f_n(x) d\mu(x)$ where $f_n(x) = |x| min(|x|, n)$ and $\mu(x)$ is the appropriate probability measure. To use the DCT, we would need the $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for some integrable function $g(x)$. If I am understanding correctly, you are proposing using $g(x) = |x|$ but that doesn't dominate the $f_n$. Maybe I'm still missing something?

We are not dominating $f_n$ but $\frac{1}{n}f_n$. As the goal is to show that we have $o(n)$, we first divide everything by $n$.

Gotcha, thanks!
